# Como puedo incluir una imagen como atributo en la creación de una clase?

Tags: java

Estoy intentando crear una clase en JAVA para almacenar características de una familia de productos a partir de unos ficheros XML. Hasta ahí todo bien, el parseo de datos tiene más problema, con documentbuilder, y tal.

El tema está en que uno de los atributos que me piden, es que se muestre la imagen del producto.
La imagen está en un fichero localizado, no hay problema, pero como indico el tipo de dato para la imagen al declarar la clase?

Es decir, por ejemplo, declaro nombre, descripción, precio de la siguiente manera:

```
private Strting Nombre;
private String Parrafo;
private Double Precio;
....
```

pero como declaro la imagen asociada dentro de la clase como atributo??

Si alguien me puede ayudar lo agradecería infinito. :)

Comment: Si lo vas a almacenar como path a un archivo o la imagen en sí como base64 por ejemplo entonces sería un String. Si querés guardar el archivo como bytes puede ser byte[].

Answer (score 0):

```
private Image imagen=ImageIO.read(new File(StringDeLaRutaUbicacionArchivo));
```

En caso que sea un ImageIcon, se tendria:

```
private ImageIcon imagen=new ImageIcon(StringDeLaRutaUbicacionArchivo);
```